# How to get a generated document's ID in the firestore then add subcollection into it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a todo-list, and I want to enable users to add the task in the list. However, I am troubled in getting document id.

Here are 2 methods I have tried:

```
 this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        const currentUserUid = this.currentUser.uid;
        let collectionPath = "/userProfile/" + currentUserUid  + "/list";

        this.list = firebase.firestore().collection(collectionPath).doc()
        const listId = this.list.id; 

        this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection(collectionPath)
                  .doc(listId).collection("task")
```

Unlucky, this way createe a new document insteading of storing task into the list.

Another method is:

```
        this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        const currentUserUid = this.currentUser.uid;
        let collectionPath = "/userProfile/" + currentUserUid  + "/list";

        this.list = firebase.firestore().collection(collectionPath)
                   .get().then((snapshot) => {
                   snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                       return doc.data();                    
                   })
                   })
        const listId = this.list.id; 

        this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection(collectionPath)
                  .doc(listId).collection("task")
```

But it said listId is undefined.

Here is my firebase structure:

```
User(Collection) - User1...
                     |
                   List(Collection) - List1...
                                        |
                             (Expected)Task(Collection) - task1...
```

Amy suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll need to know the ID of the document you want to add a task to. Once you, pass it into `doc()`: `this.list = firebase.firestore().collection(collectionPath).doc(id)`

Comment: I got stuck on getting the ID of the document actually.

Comment: @Andrewsuen did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the document's ID I would suggest you take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50078997/11928130). Also maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47143846/11928130) may prove helpful. 
As for adding a subcollection to a document I would suggest you reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873465/how-to-add-sub-collection-to-a-document-in-firestore?rq=1) and the following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

Let me know if these were helpful.